# How to transfer image files and data from swift5 to the spring server?

Tags: java, ios, swift, spring, networking

I am communicating through web view. My question is to send the pictures from the mobile phone to the web view.

I call API here.  I don't know how to send it to the web view. I know how to send only the `Key,Value`,which consists of a string.

**The code I'm taking pictures of phone.**

```swift
let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()

    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
    var captureImage: UIImage!
    var flagImageSave = false

  @IBAction func btnLoadImageFromLibray(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)) {
            flagImageSave = false
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            myAlert("photo album inaccessable", message: "application cannot access the photo album")
        }
    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
         let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
            if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as NSString as String){
                captureImage =  info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
                if flagImageSave {
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(captureImage, self, nil, nil)
                }
            imgView.image = captureImage

            }else if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String){
                if flagImageSave {
                    videoURL = (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL)
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL.relativePath, self, nil, nil)          
                }     
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**API code being received by server on Sping Project**

```java
    @RequestMapping(value="/sendimage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> pr_image(HttpServletRequest webRequest
            , @RequestParam(value="image", required=false) MultipartFile image
            ) {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();


        Map<String, Object> validationMap = ValidationUtils.ValidationOfKeys(webRequest);
        if (!validationMap.get("res").equals("sucess")) return validationMap;


        String num = (webRequest.getParameter("num") != null) ? webRequest.getParameter("num") : "";

        String imagePath = "";
            if (image != null) {
                String Extension =  Config.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_EXT;
                String fileName = "_" + Utils.getCurrentTime("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
                imagePath = Define.CONTENTS_FILE_PATH_4 + fileName + Extension ;

                File saveDir = new File(Define.CONTENTS_SAVE_PATH + Define.CONTENTS_FILE_PATH_4);
                if (!saveDir.isFile()) saveDir.mkdirs();

                image.transferTo(new File(Define.CONTENTS_SAVE_PATH + imagePath));

                String fileName_thumbnail = fileName + "_thumb" + Extension;
                File thumbnail = new File(Define.CONTENTS_SAVE_PATH + Define.CONTENTS_FILE_PATH_4 + fileName_thumbnail);

                thumbnail.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Thumbnails.of(saveDir + "/" + fileName + Extension).size(Config.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_WIDTH, Config.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_HEIGHT).outputFormat("jpg").toFile(thumbnail);
            }
...
```

How can I transfer pictures with my data to spring server?

I have to send not just images, but also numbers in strings. Look at my server code.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using the `Alamofire` module.

1. You can add `'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.2'` in podfile
2. pod install

I'm use `Alamofire version 4.8.2`

**Usage**

```swift
func ImageUpload(_ image: UIImage) {
guard image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) != nil else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        let imagedata = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)
        let uploadDict = ["num": "123456789"] as [String:String]
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["key":"val"] //  Use this if you need to add api headers
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

            MultipartFormData.append(imagedata!, withName: "image" , fileName: "image.jpg" , mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for(key,value) in uploadDict{
                MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)}   
        },to: "\(url)", headers: headers, encodingCompletion: {
            EncodingResult in
            switch EncodingResult{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    guard let json = response.result.value! as? [String: Any] else {
                        return
                    }
                    print(json)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
            } 
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to convert `UIImage` to `NSData`, and upload use

```
guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else {
    return
}
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (form) in
    form.append(data, withName: "image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
}, to: url) { (result) in

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have to send not just images, but also numbers in strings. Look at my server code.

Comment: I'm not sure wether the server side API work, the http header Content-Type can only be "multipart/form-data" or "application/json". @RequestParam(value="image", required=false) MultipartFile image correspond to "multipart/form-data", but @ResponseBody correspond to "application/json". Better solution is upload the image as an URL, and post image url as a property of json to server side.